# CGO cross compile on Windows for Linux

Tags: go, cgo

Anytime I try to cross compile a piece of CGO code that relies on Linux libs on windows for Linux, the compiler throws this error:

```
# runtime/cgo
gcc_linux_amd64.c: In function '_cgo_sys_thread_start':
gcc_linux_amd64.c:63:9: error: unknown type name 'sigset_t'; did you mean '_sigset_t'?
63 |         sigset_t ign, oset;
    |         ^~~~~~~~
    |         _sigset_t
gcc_linux_amd64.c:68:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'sigfillset' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
68 |         sigfillset(&ign);
    |         ^~~~~~~~~~
gcc_linux_amd64.c:63:23: error: unused variable 'oset' [-Werror=unused-variable]
63 |         sigset_t ign, oset;
    |                       ^~~~
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

My env variables are:

```
$env:CGO_ENABLED=1
$env:GOOS="linux"
$env:GOARCH="amd64"
$env:CC="x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc"
```

I am using MinGW as `x86_64-12.2.0-release-win32-seh-ucrt-rt_v10-rev2.7z`  download from their official github release page.

and I am compiling using this command:

```
go build
```

Although we do have a CI/CD pipeline and I can build it inside of a Linux container, I'm curious how can I achieve this on Windows without having to actually build the app in a Linux environment.

I am using libraries that rely on C code (i.e ZSTD) and this has become kind of a headache for me.